# To join or not to join on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have this hypothetical situation where there is a person and the address where he/she lives.

I know I can either create a collection `Person` (with name, age etc) and a collection `Address` (with a ""foreign key"" person_id and then perform a join in order to find the person's name inside address collection) or create only one collection Address and, instead of person_id, I can have person's properties inside address collection.

I looked for the most appropriate solution on the internet and I found both. I've already read about $lookup and I'm still confused about the solution.

I'm not an expert on NoSQL, and I'd like to know more opinions about what's the most appropriate solution to implement this.

Comment: There are many creteria to consider, but one basic rule, is data that are queried together its best to be together(embed). This allows simpler schema with less collections, more natural representation, and less need for joins. I think its best to think to embed, and only when needed to seperate to multiple collections. Also you can always duplicate data, to make data exists in many places, this is good if those data are not changed often.

Comment: You know opinion-based questions are not welcome on this site. Try to think about the problem from data-retrieval point of view, not from object relations typical for sql. There are no normal forms, and data duplication is not a crime. You can use nosql for your benefit or shoot yourself in a foot.  SQL is based on relation algebra invented a century before computers. NoSQL are niche products to solve practical implementational problems ignored by the SQL theory. Mongo focuses on speed,  scalability and fault tolerance. How to use it is on you.

Comment: Why not embed the addresses in the Person collection?

Comment: Yes, embedding seams the most appropriate solution here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, guys. I appreciate you used your time for answering a doubt of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this use-case, it would be best to keep all user addresses inside the user itself.

So, you would add `address` property to the user model, that will be an array, and you put all user addresses inside.

This approach is best here because of the following:

1. When you fetch the user, the address information will be there already, so you don't have to perform `$lookup`, which will increase the performance.
2. You don't have to maintain 2 collections, but only one.
3. You don't have to be worry about scaling, because each user will probably have only a few addresses, and not thousands or tens of thousands of them.

---

**Note:** If use-case is that the user can potentially have thousands or tens of thousands of addresses, then you should go ahead with 2 collections, because each MongoDB document have the limit of 16MB, so you can not put all addresses inside the user.

Comment: I appreciate for your time and answer. Thank you very much, @NeNaD.